# Can this code violate the single responsability principle?

Tags: php, publish

This is a short preview of the code. I have a class Publish whose main job is to publish messages.

```
class Publisher
{  
    private $producer;
    private $adapter;

    public function publish($message)
    {
        $message = $this->adapter->adapt($message);
        $this->producer->publish($message);
    }
}
```

The question is, am i violating the single responsability principle if i'm also adapting the message in the publish method?

Comment: What do you mean by "adapting"?

Comment: Formatting the message so it can respect the standard accepted by the publisher.

Comment: No, because this is changing the message *soley* and *always* for output by this method. This change is nessecary for this method to work. As long as this change is not saved to the original `$message` data.